# AppleScript: adding a menu into Address Book

Tags: menu, applescript, addressbook

I wrote an Apple Script which allows easy adding a iCal's todo, associated to a contact from Address Book. The script is working as expected when I'm launching it from the AppleScript Editor.

In order this script becomes useful for me, I need to be able to launch it from Address Book directly. Do you know how can I do that ?
Idealy, I would like to add a menu entry into the contextual menu displayed clicking with the right button into the contacts list.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: belongs on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) or the built in Scripts menu (Applescript Editor -> Prefs -> Show Scripts in Menu Bar).

Comment: @Ryan : Thanks for your advise. At this time, I used the Mac's script menu to call shortly my script.